# C# - how to delete row in realm - android xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, realm

i tried this method that I created but it prompts me an error:

**Realms.RealmInvalidObjectException:This object is detached. Was it deleted from the realm?'**

```
    public void deleteFromDatabase(List<CashDenomination> denom_list)
    {
        using (var transaction = Realm.GetInstance(config).BeginWrite())
        {
            Realm.GetInstance(config).Remove(denom_list[0]);
            transaction.Commit();
        }
    }
```

what is the proper coding for deleting records from database in realm in C# type of coding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing it the right way. The error message you are getting indicates that the object was removed already. Are you sure it still exists in the realm?

**UPDATE:**

*I decided to update this answer because my comment on the other answer was a bit hard to read.*

Your original code should work fine. However, if you want `deleteFromDatabase` to accept lists with `CashDenomination` instances that either have been removed already or perhaps were never added to the realm, you would need to add a check. Furthermore, note that you should hold on to your `Realm` instance and use it in the transaction you created. In most cases, you want to keep it around even longer, though there is little overhead to obtaining it via `GetInstance`.

```
public void deleteFromDatabase(List<CashDenomination> denom_list)
{
    if (!denom_list[0].IsValid) // If this object is not in the realm, do nothing.
        return;

    var realm = Realm.GetInstance(config);
    using (var transaction = realm.BeginWrite())
    {
        realm.Remove(denom_list[0]);
        transaction.Commit();
    }
}
```

Now, if you want to use identifiers, you could look it up like you do, but still just use `Remove`:

```
public void deleteFromDatabase(int denom_id)
{
    var realm = Realm.GetInstance(config);

    var denom = realm.All<CashDenomination>().FirstOrDefault(c => c.denom_id == denom_id);
    if (denom == null)  // If no entry with this id exists, do nothing.
        return;

    using (var transaction = realm.BeginWrite())
    {
        realm.Remove(denom);
        transaction.Commit();
    }
}
```

Finally, if your `CashDenomination` has `denom_id` marked as `PrimaryKey`, you could look it up like this:

```
public void deleteFromDatabase(int denom_id)
{
    var realm = Realm.GetInstance(config);

    var denom = realm.ObjectForPrimaryKey<CashDenomination>(denom_id);
    if (denom == null)  // If no entry with this id exists, do nothing.
        return;

    using (var transaction = realm.BeginWrite())
    {
        realm.Remove(denom);
        transaction.Commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: I already deleted about .First() because I learned that it is not a part of delete by a select query in realm . It is not related to the question so I removed it.

But as part of my question, how can I check if it is really removed or not without exception? :)

Comment: @jace you could try `RealmObject.IsValid`. If the object was deleted, it will return false.

Comment: I tried it here but no .IsValid is available for realm instance, Realm itself or in my object to delete :( am I doing it wrong?

        public void deleteFromDatabase(int form_id)
        {
            realm.Write(() =>
            {
                var cashflow_form = realm.All<Cashflow_Form>().Where(c => c.form_id == form_id);
                realm.RemoveRange(((RealmResults<Cashflow_Form>)cashflow_form));
                realm.IsValid();
                Realm.IsValid();
                cashflow_form.IsValid();
            });
        }

Comment: ow I found it here --->>>

Comment: RealmObject asd = new RealmObject();
            asd.IsValid()

but how can I use RealmObject? since my code is from my third comment.

and also how can I format my comment to readable comment? It looks worst when I enter it LOL

Comment: Add these ` <-- backticks around it

Answer (score 1):

```
public void deleteFromDatabase(Realm realm, long cashDenominatorId)
{
    realm.Write(() => 
    {
         var cashDenominator = realm.All<Person>().Where(c => c.Id == cashDenominatorId);
         Realm.RemoveRange<CashDenomination>(((RealmResults<CashDenomination>)cashDenominator));
    });
}
```

Which you would call as

```
Realm realm = Realm.GetInstance(config);
var denom_list = ...
// ...
deleteFromDatabase(realm, denom_list[0].id);
```

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IQueryable<RBOS_2._0.Cashflow_Denomination>' to 'Realms.RealmResults<RBOS_2._0.Cashflow_Denomination>' RBOS 2.0 D:\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\RBOS 2.0\RBOS 2.0\Realm\RealmDatabase.cs 67 Active


it gives an error to me

Comment: Hm, what a silly API the Xamarin Realm has. Anyways, added the necessary cast.

Answer (score 1):

I already made it having this code :) thanks to @EpicPandaForce 's answer.

```
    public void deleteFromDatabase(int denom_ID, int form_ID)
    {            
        //Realm realm;
        //and
        //RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration(dbPath, true);
        //was initialized at the top of my class

        realm = Realm.GetInstance(config);

        realm.Write(() =>
        {
            var cashflow_denom = realm.All<CashDenomination>().Where(c => c.denom_id == denom_ID);
            var cashflow_form = realm.All<CashForm>().Where(c => c.form_id == form_ID);

            realm.RemoveRange(((RealmResults<CashDenomination>)cashflow_denom));
            realm.RemoveRange(((RealmResults<CashForm>)cashflow_form));
        });
    }
```

it is now deleting my data without exception :)

Comment: I am happy this works for you but it shouldn't be necessary to use `RemoveRange` -- that method is intended to remove multiple objects at a time. `Realm.Remove()` is meant for removing just a single object. You should achieve the same with something like:

`var o = realm.All<CashDenomination>().FirstOrDefault(c => c.denom_id == denom_ID); if (o != null) realm.Write(() => { realm.Remove(o); });`

Furthermore, if `denom_id` is marked as primary key, you could use [ObjectForPrimaryKey](https://realm.io/docs/xamarin/0.78.0/api/class_realms_1_1_realm.html#adbc5b4c8a164d9dcdec0393b9f9f4f23)