# Type or namespace RealmQuery not found

Tags: c#, linq, xamarin, xamarin.forms, realm

I've to delete multiple element with same identifier in **Realm** istance in my **Xamarin.Forms** app.

I tried to do the following code after read [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40014094/c-sharp-how-to-delete-row-in-realm-android-xamarin)

```
realm.Write(() =>
{
    var alle = realm.All<Foo>().Where(b => b.id_x == x);
    Realm.RemoveRange<Foo>(((RealmResults<Foo>)alle));
});
```

but I get an error about missing **type or namespace RealmResult**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API changed, `IQueryable` is now returned versus `RealmResults`, now you can do:

```
realm.Write(() =>
{
    var filteredList = realm.All<POCO>().Where(obj => obj.key == "SO");
    realm.RemoveRange(filteredList);
});
```

#### Refer to the Unit tests for Remove:

Ref: https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/blob/b9920b7b3cb77c54c1850fe26668959797640d79/Shared/Tests.Shared/RemoveTests.cs

#### Change to API:

> `RealmResults<T>` is now marked `internal` and `Realm.All<T>()` will instead return `IQueryable<T>`.

Re: https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/pull/942